# How to remove transparency from search interface?

Tags: unity

The search interface of Ubuntu search has a strong transparency. However, if there is any window open on the current workspace, the Ubuntu search interface is pretty hard to use read, because the applications below shine through.

How can I change the appearance of Ubuntu search and remove this annoying transparency? Unity tweak tool does not seem to have an setting for that.

Any hint is much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds to me like you disabled the blur of the launcher.

Comment: Nope, the underlying windows are blurry when the search panel is up. But it's still hard to work with all the stuff shining through (albeit blurred)...

Answer (score 1):

Solution is Compiz CCSM. In section "workspace" there's a menu item "Ubuntu Unity Plugin". There you will find the option "Background color", which refers to the background of the "Dash". That's what the search interface seems to be called actually. Use this background color option to set color and transparency of the dash's background. What a relieve to finally stop being distracted by the blurry stuff from underneath this dash panel...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old now, but starting with Ubuntu 15.10 (I believe), you can turn off transparency in CCSM -> Unity and choose force low graphics mode. I am hoping this would get put into Appearance in Unity Control Center.  As it comes in handy, I don't want to dig through CCSM.

Answer (score 0):

In 15.10, there is no "workspace". If you search for "workspace", you get "Workspace Naming".
There is also no CCSM->Unity.

There IS a category Desktop, with "Ubuntu Unity Plugin".
Under the General tab, there is Panel Opacity. Mine was set to 0.1. I changed it to 1.0. This made the icons visible, but not the text and not the background.
Under the Launcher tab, set Launcher Opacity to 1.0. This fixes the opacity in the launcher.

However, the Unity Search still has unreadable text, and a background gradient that makes half the icons unreadable.